# How to use sed command to replace text between two single quotation marks in a file?

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have the file: `Address.txt`

Address.txt

```
Name = John
Initial = 'J'
Phone = 123-456-789
Home = '1234 North Street'
Work = '5678 South Street'
```

How can I replace the text between specific two `'` marks at specific using `sed` command or any other terminal command?

For example, changing `Address.txt` to:

```
Name = John
Initial = 'J'
Phone = 123-456-789
Home = '147 East Avenue'
Work = '5678 South Street'
```

Update 1:
I would like to change the information in the line that starts with `Home =` 
The information after `Home =`  is not fixed. It could be anything. For example, `'Hello'`, `None'`, or even `''` (nothing).

Comment: Please, be more specific. What is the rule? What text should be replaced? Is it the 4th line, or `Home =`, or do you want to replace `North Street`, or...

Comment: `sed "s/^Home .*/Home = '147 East Avenue'/" file`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the above example you could do this:

```
sed "/^Home/s/'[^']*'/'147 East Avenue'/" Address.txt
```

The /Home/ matches on the line of interest, and s// command replaces everything between the two single quotes including the quotes themselves.  If you want to edit the file change `sed` to `sed -i`.

Comment: That works perfectly. Is there any command that can extract the selected text before doing the replacement process?

Comment: @nodymoha: Take a look at sed's `w` command.

Comment: @AllanWind Thank you so much! that is exactly what I needed.